# How do i send the SMS message using Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I can't able to send the Text messages using Amazon Simple Notification Services(SNS). I have tried with API and Amazon Console. Both are not working. Please help me to solve the issues.

I am using Amazon Free plan account.

Comment: What errors are you getting, if any? What's your setup like?

Comment: Amazon shows the successful message but I can't receive it from my mobile. In the Amazon dashboard they shows the failed report.

Comment: What info is in the failure report in the AWS dashboard?

Comment: Amazon shows Internal error in the CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Sns support two diffrent type of messages

- Promotions message
- Transaction message

If your mobile register do not disturb or many service provider not allowed promotions messages like Verizon

```java
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = 
       new HashMap<String,MessageAttributeValue>();
        
       smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType",new 
 MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("Transactional").withDataType("String"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To discover why an SMS message was not sent, you can **enable logging in CloudWatch Logs**.

From [Viewing Amazon CloudWatch metrics and logs for SMS deliveries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html#sns-viewing-cloudwatch-logs):

> You can collect information about successful and unsuccessful SMS message deliveries by enabling Amazon SNS to write to Amazon CloudWatch Logs. For each SMS message that you send, Amazon SNS will write a log that includes the message price, the success or failure status, the reason for failure (if the message failed), the message dwell time, and other information.

I did this recently to discover why my SMS was not successful. The message said that my carrier refused the message. I discovered that this was because I was using a Custom Sender ID. Once I removed that setting, I could successfully send SMS messages.

Comment: I am using both Custom Sender ID and default Sender ID. But both are not working yet.

Comment: I suggest that you turn on the logging and see whether you can get a better error message.